# Web audio API sound works on desktop and Android, but doesn't on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari, web-audio-api

I've read a lot of topics and questions on this matter, but I can't find a solution. I can play sound on every Android browser, on every desktop browser, but not on Safari on iPhone 5c.
I'm trying to do it with Web Audio API (I'm definitly not an expert), here's my code:

```
window.addEventListener ('load', loadSound);
canvas.addEventListener ('touchend', loadSound);
canvas.addEventListener ('mouseup', loadSound);

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioContext = new window.AudioContext();

var playSoundBuffer;
var source;

function loadSound() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var audioURL = "media/sound/WW_start.wav";

        request.open("GET", audioURL, true);
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
        request.onload = function() {
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
            playSoundBuffer = buffer;
            playSound();
            }, function(error) {
                console.error("Error in sound", error);
            });                 
        request.send();
        }
    }, 50);
}

function playSound() {
    source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = playSoundBuffer; 
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

I also tried with source.noteOn(), source.noteOn(0), webkitAudioContext...

Answer (score -1):

Howler is the solution:

```
<script src="lib/howler.js-master/howler.js-master/dist/howler.js"></script>
```

...

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['file.wav', 'file.mp3', 'file.ogg'],
  volume: 1,
  buffer: false
});

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  sound.play();
}, false);
```